# does servercore:ltsc2019 image support 8.3 (SFN) names?

Tags: windows, docker, windows-server-2019

I have a script using 8.3 filename (C:\Progra~1 ) and it doesn't work on docker image mcr.microsoft.com/windows/servercore:ltsc2019.
I checked and `dir /x` actually doesn't show short format like it does on windows server 2019 OS.
[Windows Server 2019 OS](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YwSdw.png)
Is this a known issue or maybe windows docker images do not support it anymore?

Comment: 8.3 filenames can be removed. Also you should check the file system setting: `fsutil 8dot3name query`

Comment: The registry state is: 2 (Per volume setting - the default).